# How to make a function or constructor that accepts array of any rank

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a wrapper struct around a vector and a shape, like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct array_type {
    std::array<std::size_t, N> shape;
    std::vector<float> data;
};
```

I would like to be able to construct an `array_type` from any array `float[N]`, `float[N][M]`, etc.

Currently, I have a function for each rank, e.g.

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
array_type<1> _1d(const deel::formal::float_type (&values)[N]) {
    return {{N},
            std::vector<float_type>(
                reinterpret_cast<const float_type*>(values),
                reinterpret_cast<const float_type*>(values) + N)};
}

template <std::size_t N>
array_type<2> _2d(const deel::formal::float_type (&values)[N][M]) {
    return {{N, M},
            std::vector<float_type>(
                reinterpret_cast<const float_type*>(values),
                reinterpret_cast<const float_type*>(values) + N * M)};
}
```

I would like to write something like:

```
template <class Array>
array_type<std::rank_v<Array>> make_array(Array const&);
```

...but that does not work for initializer list:

```
auto arr1 = _1d({1, 2, 3}); // Ok
auto arr2 = make_array({1, 2, 3}); // Ko
```

Is there a way to have this `make_array`? Or (since I think it's not possible), to have at least something like `make_array<1>({1, 2, 3})` where the rank is explicitly specified?

Answer (score 2):

`array_type::shape` can be generated with `std::extent` with a bit of template meta programming:

```
template<typename Array, std::size_t... I>
auto extents_impl(const Array& a, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::array{std::extent_v<Array, I>...};
}

template<typename Array>
auto extents(const Array& a)
{
    return extents_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<std::rank_v<Array>>());
}
```

With this, `make_array` can be written as:

```
template <class Array, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_all_extents_t<Array>>, float>, int> = 0> // magic incantation :)
array_type<std::rank_v<Array>> make_array(Array const& a)
{
    array_type<std::rank_v<Array>> ret {
        .shape = extents(a),
        .data = std::vector<float>(sizeof a / sizeof(float)),
    };
    std::memcpy(ret.data.data(), &a, sizeof a);
    return ret;
}
```

I use `memcpy` to avoid potential pointer type aliasing violations and the technicality of iterating outside the bounds of sub array being UB according to strict interpretation of the standard.

> ...but that does not work for initializer list:

Add one overload:

```
template <std::size_t N>
array_type<1> make_array(float const (&a)[N])
{
    return make_array<float[N]>(a);
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify the array type in the call:

```
make_array<float[2][3]>({{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6}});
```

This requires no overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I explained, this does not work for `make_array({1, 2, 3})` due to the template type `Array`, which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @Holt Oh. I thought the whole point was not having to write a separate function for each rank.

Comment: Well, both actually... but the blocking point in my implementation was (is) really the non-deduce-able template type, I might have been clearer though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still need an overload per rank (although each overload is a bit smaller). Also, could clarify and point to references for this *I use memcpy to avoid potential pointer type aliasing violations and the technicality of iterating outside the bounds of sub array being UB according to strict interpretation of the standard.*?

Answer (score 0):

`T (&&)[N]` is suggested when you want a function template to accept a *braced-init-list* and deduce its length, furthermore, you can use `T (&&)[M][N]`, `T (&&)[M][N][O]` ... to deduce the lengths of each rank (sadly, there is nothing like `T (&&)[N]...[Z]` to accept array with arbitrary rank).

so you can provide overloading function like this:

```cpp
// attention that `T (&&)[N][M]` is `Y (&&)[N]` where `Y` is `T[M]`.

template<typename T, size_t N>
using Array1D_t = T[N];
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
using Array2D_t = Array1D_t<Array1D_t<T, N>, M>;
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N, size_t O>
using Array3D_t = Array1D_t<Array2D_t<T, N, O>, M>;
// ...

// assume the max rank is X.

template<typename T, size_t N>
array_type<1> make_array(Array1D_t<T, N>&& v);
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
array_type<2> make_array(Array2D_t<T, M, N>&& v);
template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N, size_t O>
array_type<3> make_array(Array3D_t<T, M, N, O>&& v);
// ...
```

and then, it will be okay for `make_array({1, 2, 3})`, `make_array({{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}})` ..., except the rank is larger than `X`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's about what I'm doing right now and what is already in the question (I only have different names for the function, but that does not really matter).

Comment: @Holt I'm confused about what you want. `T(&&)[N]` is the only way to make it deducible, but it could never be adapted for arbitrary rank. you want `make_array<1>({1, 2, 3})`, `make_array<2>({{1, 2, 3}})` instead of `make_array({1, 2, 3})` and `make_array({{1, 2, 3}})`, why?

Comment: I don't want `make_array<1>(...)` instead of `make_array(...)`, you did not read the question properly. What I would like is a generic `make_array` that I don't have to overload for each rank. And yes, maybe it's not possible, but I'm not 100% sure, even with both current answers. The point about `make_array<1>(...)` was simply that it could be easier to implement than `make_array(...)` since you could rely on an intermediate type to generate the array type for the argument.

Comment: okay, that's easy to say, impossible. the reason is what I said before: *there is nothing like `T (&&)[N]...[Z]` to accept array with arbitrary rank.* you can provide a feature request for standard, which demands to allow `T (&&)...[Ns]` or partial specializations of type alias.

Comment: even that you provide the rank makes no sense. a deducible brace-init-list could only be that form. you can make an array type with the rank, but in this case you can't deduce its lengths of each rank.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Regarding your second-to last comment you make a shortcut in that you assume that it's `T (&)[N]...[Z]`, and yes, that's impossible, but maybe there is a way by using an intermediate structure so that by explicitly passing the rank `R` you could have `some_struct<R>::type` pointing to the right array-type (or maybe a function accepting the right array type). I'm not saying it's possible, but you should not assume it's not simply because the easy way is not possible.]

Comment: @Holt I know that maybe you want `helper<R>::template type<Ns...>&&` to match the initializer. but it can not work around the problem: the argument type must be `T(&&)[M]` or its type alias, instead of a recursive definition. it means that `helper` must be defined individually for each rank. type alias `helper<R>::type` can not have variadic template parameters, it will cause mismatched like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/evfY41).

Comment: I'm not easily negating your thought, but I know it will never satisfy both the rule of template argument deduction and the preconditions of deducible brace-init-list. and in fact I had ever tried it but finally chose the overload functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have this make_array?

I don't think so (but, to be honest, I'm not able to demonstrate it's impossible).

> Or (since I think it's not possible), to have at least something like make_array<1>({1, 2, 3}) where the rank is explicitly specified?

I don't see a way also in this case.

But... if you accept that the **sizes** are explicitly specified... you can write a recursive custom type traits to construct the final type

```
// declararion and ground case
template <typename T, std::size_t ...>
struct get_ranked_array
 { using type = T; };

// recursive case
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim0, std::size_t ... Dims>
struct get_ranked_array<T, Dim0, Dims...>
   : public get_ranked_array<T[Dim0], Dims...>
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
using get_ranked_array_t = typename get_ranked_array<T, Dims...>::type;
```

and the make function simply become

```
template <std::size_t ... Dims>
auto make_ranked_array (get_ranked_array_t<float, Dims...> const & values)
   -> array_type<sizeof...(Dims)>
 {
   return {{Dims...},
      std::vector<float>(
         reinterpret_cast<float const *>(values),
         reinterpret_cast<float const *>(values) + (Dims * ...))};
 }
```

You can use it as follows

```
auto arr1 = make_ranked_array<3u>({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}); 
auto arr2 = make_ranked_array<3u, 2u>({ {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f},
                                        {4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f} });
```

If you want, you can maintain the deduction of the last size, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template <std::size_t N>
struct array_type
 {
   std::array<std::size_t, N> shape;
   std::vector<float> data;
 };

// declararion and ground case
template <typename T, std::size_t ...>
struct get_ranked_array
 { using type = T; };

// recursive case
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim0, std::size_t ... Dims>
struct get_ranked_array<T, Dim0, Dims...>
   : public get_ranked_array<T[Dim0], Dims...>
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
using get_ranked_array_t = typename get_ranked_array<T, Dims...>::type;

template <std::size_t ... Dims>
auto make_ranked_array (get_ranked_array_t<float, Dims...> const & values)
   -> array_type<sizeof...(Dims)>
 {
   return {{Dims...},
      std::vector<float>(
         reinterpret_cast<float const *>(values),
         reinterpret_cast<float const *>(values) + (Dims * ...))};
 }

int main ()
 {
   auto arr1 = make_ranked_array<3u>({1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}); 
   auto arr2 = make_ranked_array<3u, 2u>({ {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f},
                                           {4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f} }); 

   static_assert ( std::is_same_v<decltype(arr1), array_type<1>> );
   static_assert ( std::is_same_v<decltype(arr2), array_type<2>> );
 }
```